# Java: Display request of an HttpURLConnection before sending

Tags: java, request, httpurlconnection

I want to make some API calls to a server using `HttpURLConnection`. But the requests are not successful, returning:

```
<error>
  <http_status>400 Bad Request</http_status>
  <message>Unexpected request Content-Type header ''. Expecting 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'.</message>
</error>
```

So I want to check what the "real" content is that is being sent to the server. By real content I mean the exact HTTP request.

Any ideas how I can see this?

**Edit:**
Based on the first answers here I should clarify my problem: I want to avoid using an external program like HTTP sniffer or anything and I was hoping that there is a function or a property or whatever that holds the information I am looking for.

If that is not the case, does someone know if this information can be manually rebuilt (for example by calling several functions like getRequestMethod(), etc.)

I am facing this problem kinda often so that it's worth the effort to build such functionality myself. Just need to know how :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable wire logging for a java HttpURLConnection traffic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445919/how-to-enable-wire-logging-for-a-java-httpurlconnection-traffic)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can put the HttpURLConnection in debug mode by enabling java.logging with

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties
```

and put in logging.properties (by default in JRE_HOME\lib) the following property

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = ALL
```

Comment: I dont really know what I have to do with the line of code you mentioned above.. where do I need to put this? (using eclipse as IDE)

Comment: You also need to set "java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST"

Comment: @Hirnhamster, in the Run Configuration - Arguments tab , you add into the VM arguments section.

Comment: Where do you see the content of the "real" sent data?

Comment: I tried it on JDK 7, and it worked for me after I changed to
`sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = FINEST`

Answer (score 5):

tcpdump will work, but it can be hard to make it do what you want. NetCat is more user-friendly (here's the project page: http://netcat.sourceforge.net/ - most Unix platforms already include it).

```
nc -l 9999
```

This will listen on TCP port 9999, and when an HTTP client connects, it'll print out the full text of the request.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted solution did not work for me. But what did was

```
static {
    ConsoleHandler handler = new ConsoleHandler();
    handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    Logger log = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("");
    log.addHandler(handler);
    log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all"); 
}
```

Comment: How to log body also using this?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like tcpdump, which can dump the actual network packets that are emitted or received by your computer.

Answer (score 0):

On JDK 11 I was able to log all the http connections, setting `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level` to `FINEST` and adding the following lines in the file `logging.properties` which is by default in %JAVA_HOME%/conf:

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = FINEST
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```