# When using nimbus-jose-jwt, with RemoteJWKSet can i find(see in logs) when request are made to remote url for cache update etc

Tags: java, jwt, nimbus, jjwt, nimbus-jose-jwt

I am using nimbus-jose-jwt with [RemoteJWKSet](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/8.19/com/nimbusds/jose/jwk/source/RemoteJWKSet.html) and would like to find(see in logs) when requests are made to remote url for cache update etc.
For the spring boot app, I set `logging.level.com.nimbusds=TRACE` but could not find any logging related to calls to remote url for retrieving the jwks from remote server.
Is there a way to find when a call is made to remote server to retrieve the jwks.

Edit:
Should anyone want to look at the code, the required jwks code is uploaded on github:  [NimbusJose-JWKSCaching](https://github.com/ramshers/NimbusJose-JWKSCaching).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the source code of the RemoteJWKSet.java](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/src/master/src/main/java/com/nimbusds/jose/jwk/source/RemoteJWKSet.java) it does not do any logging on its own. It uses [DefaultResourceRetriever class](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/src/b7937f477c30250ec568cb3842033a1afd7ce19d/src/main/java/com/nimbusds/jose/util/DefaultResourceRetriever.java#lines-234) to download JWKS resource from remote URL. The `DefaultResourceRetriever` does not log anything explicitly either. What it does though, it uses standard Java [java.net.HttpURLConnection class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to request the JWKS resource.

This means that you can use standard Java logging facilities to log information you need. Here are few answers that might be helpful to achieve this:

- [Java: Display request of an HttpURLConnection before sending](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428906/12092416)
- [Log all network interactions of Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512522/log-all-network-interactions-of-java-application)
- [limiting java ssl debug logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23659564/limiting-java-ssl-debug-logging)

Comment: welcome and thanks for your suggestion. ++1 i tried `logging.level.root=TRACE` and `logging.level.java.net.HttpURLConnection=TRACE` and `logging.level.sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level=TRACE` . But found no additional logging. Could there be anything wrong with my setup.

Comment: I think you need to change logging level of the handler as well. If you are using console logging handler then change its logging level to ALL like this `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL`

Comment: if you don't mind - can you guide me in terms of spring boot. This log tracing is quite crucial for me.

Comment: Actually, this is not specific to SpringBoot. This logging facility is provided by Java. You can enable Java logging by specifying logging properties file via JVM startup parameters using `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/app.properties`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960099/how-to-set-up-java-logging-using-a-properties-file-java-util-logging) about how to provide logging.properties. For more details you can look at [Java Logging Overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/core/java-logging-overview.htm#JSCOR-GUID-B83B652C-17EA-48D9-93D2-563AE1FF8EDA)

Comment: [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/sponomarev72/7c35380e7ea610b8a150f4cdd1e87039) with minimal logging configuration that should be enough in your case.

Comment: Sergei, I have tried the things suggested but nothing worked in tracing/logging the requests made to jwks url. 
I have extracted the jwks code from my application and uploaded it to github: [NimbusJose-JWKSCaching](https://github.com/ramshers/NimbusJose-JWKSCaching).
It will be of great help if you could guide on how to enable logging of jwks request over this project. I think it bit of much to ask, but this logging is crucial for me.
I have added your github user as commiter to the project just in case if you wish to commit directly to the project.

Comment: @samshers I will take a look at it a bit later. Meanwhile, you can use [the test program to print the logger tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44888306/12092416). This will prove if your static configuration file is actually being used at runtime.

Comment: I took a look at your code. You added the `logging.properties` file as a resource but did not register. [This page](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/logging/loading-properties.html) shows different ways to set logging properties. Look in the *Loading logging.properties from classpath* section.

Comment: Sergei, sorry i am not much aware about logging using logging.properties. but following your suggestion - i tried running the spring boot app with jvm option `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties` but it did not work.   Basically Spring boot logging takes care of everthing if i provide - `logging.level.sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection=TRACE`. So if any logging is done by `HttpURLConnection` class it will be logged/captured.

Comment: to not confuse any further, i am removing the logging.properties file, so we can focus on spring boot logging solely. If we can solve it.. that's great. Else i will try to raise this issue on nimbus jose project directly.

Comment: @samshers `HttpURLConnection` class does logging using JUL not SLF4J which is configured by default in SpringBoot. I have not tried it myself but I think you have to enable JUL logging by providing `java.util.logging.config.file` and then, if you really want it to be part of SpringBoot logging, you might want to try using [JUL2SLF4J bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)

Comment: Putting bridging JUL to SLF4J aside - I suggest you to do this: save the logging.properties file somewhere in your file system. Start the SpringBoot application using `-Djava.util.logging.config.file=<absolute path to /logging.properties>`. At least, this should show you the logs by `HttpUrlConnection` and you can confirm it is working. Also, add code [to print logger tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44882648/logging-not-showing/44888306#44888306) on application start and share the output of it.

Comment: many thanks for your continuous involvement. I will try and if i have any progress I will update here.