# Is it possible to dump the HTTP Headers when using java.net.HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, http-headers, wireshark, apache-httpcomponents, charles-proxy

I'm debugging some code that was written using `java.net.HttpURLConnection`. I'd like to set a property to enable logging of HTTP Request and Response headers as is possible in the Apache HTTP Components library with the `org.apache.http.headers` category.

Is this possible with HttpURLConnection? Do I need to breakout Charles Proxy or Wireshark?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable wire logging for a java HttpURLConnection traffic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445919/how-to-enable-wire-logging-for-a-java-httpurlconnection-traffic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Sun's HttpURLConnection source](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java/?v=source) there is some logging support via JUL.

This would require setting up java.util.logging with `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level=ALL`.

See http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-debug-HttpURLConnection-problem.html for example.

There is also system property `-Djavax.net.debug=all`. But it's mainly [useful for SSL debugging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html).

BTW, Wireshark is also a rather easy option.

Comment: This gave me exactly what I needed. The source is always the source of truth so I should've looked there first but this seems like nice functionality that I'm not sure why it didn't make it to the Javadoc.