# Dump http headers

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I would like to enable dumping of HTTP headers in a JAX-WS RI client.

I do not want to dump the actual content, only the headers. Beware that under the hood JAX-WS RI uses [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) so please don't reply with something related to Apache's HttpClient.

I need to enable it programmatically, not by way of a configuration file.

I'm aware of the answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295400/is-it-possible-to-dump-the-http-headers-when-using-java-net-httpurlconnection), but I'm really [struggling to make that work with Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815048/jdk-how-to-enable-platformlogger-programmatically) so I'm wondering if I'm going about this the wrong way. In essence what I want to do is to be able to see the HTTP headers on the http traffic underlying JAX-WS and I don't really care how it is achieved as long as I can enable it programmatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065737/how-to-log-apache-cxf-soap-request-and-soap-response-using-log4j if you need just headers, you can write your own inceptor (it's simple)

Comment: @MGorgon. Wouldn't that be specific to Apache CXF?. As the question states I'm using JAX-WS RI, aka Metro.

Answer (score 0):

This section of [JAX-WS guide](https://metro.java.net/nonav/1.2/guide/Access_HTTP_headers_in_a_Handler.html) about using handlers to access HTTP headers might help.

Comment: Thank you for that. The method in the link is part of JAX-WS itself. I don't think it will work if you get a JAX-WS exception. What I'm looking for has to be 'below' the JAX-WS layer otherwise you cannot be certain it will actually be triggered. Just to give you an example: A typical web service workflow also includes the client fetching the WSDL from the server which is not a SOAP request (yet part of what JAX-WS does) and the method in the link will certainly not work in that case.