# Jsoup http logging

Tags: java, html, http, logging, jsoup

Is there a way to log the http request and response?
Let's assume the below request

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("LOGIN_URL_HERE")
            .data("user", "USER", "pass", "PASS")
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute();
```

How can I log the http request and response? Please mind that I want the HTTP and not just the HTML that will be parsed.

Comment: see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445919/how-to-enable-wire-logging-for-a-java-httpurlconnection-traffic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default jsoup uses a implementation of `java.net.HttpURLConnection` So I suppose you need to turn on logging for that implementation (probably: `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)` or for `java.net`.

There is a system property that will enable logging for java net utils

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

Answer (score 2):

As `Jsoup` lacks logging (version I'm using: `1.12.1`) and using the `-Djavax.net.debug=all` JVM argument logs are too verbose, the best way I found is to decorate the `HttpConnection` class, so one can customize what is logged. To achive this, the `execute` method call needs to be surrounded by logging the properties of the `Connection.Request` and `Connection.Response`.

Sample implementation using `SLF4J`:

```java
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DiagnosticConnection extends HttpConnection {
    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DiagnosticConnection.class);

    @Override
    public Connection.Response execute() throws IOException {
        log(this.request());
        Connection.Response response = super.execute();
        log(response);

        return response;
    }

    public static Connection connect(String url) {
        Connection connection = new DiagnosticConnection();
        connection.url(url);
        return connection;
    }

    private static void log(Connection.Request request) {
        LOG.info("========================================");
        LOG.info("[url] {}", request.url());
        LOG.info("== REQUEST ==");
        logBase(request);
        LOG.info("[method] {}", request.method());
        LOG.info("[data] {}", request.data());
        LOG.info("[request body] {}", request.requestBody());
    }

    private static void log(Connection.Response response) {
        LOG.info("== RESPONSE ==");
        logBase(response);
        LOG.info("[code] {}", response.statusCode());
        LOG.info("[status msg] {}", response.statusMessage());
        LOG.info("[body] {}", response.body());
        LOG.info("========================================");
    }

    private static void logBase(Connection.Base<?> base) {
        LOG.info("[headers] {}", base.headers());
        LOG.info("[cookies] {}", base.cookies());
    }

}
```

When using the decorator, instead of `Jsoup.connect(<URL>)` you should use `DiagnosticConnection.connect(<URL>)`

Comment: I'm gettin error because `HttpConnection` has not public constructor. Error: `There is not default constructor available in 'org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection'`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Gergely Toth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58524885/6126110) response, I have created my own `LoggerHttpConnection` and I'm working with that.

```
import android.util.Log
import org.jsoup.Connection
import org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser
import java.io.InputStream
import java.net.Proxy
import java.net.URL
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory

class LoggerHttpConnection private constructor(
    private val delegate: HttpConnection,
    private val saveFile: Boolean
) : Connection {

    private val tag = "LoggerHttpConnection"

    companion object {
        fun connect(url: String, saveFile: Boolean = false): LoggerHttpConnection {
            return LoggerHttpConnection(
                HttpConnection.connect(url) as HttpConnection,
                saveFile
            )
        }
    }

    private fun log(request: Connection.Request): String {
        Log.i(tag, "========================================")
        var line = "[url] ${request.url()}"
        var log = "$line\n\n== REQUEST ==\n"
        Log.i(tag, line)

        Log.i(tag, "== REQUEST ==")
        log += logBase(request)

        line = "[method] ${request.method()}"
        log += "$line\n"
        Log.i(tag, line)

        for (data in request.data()) {
            line = "[data] ${data.key()}=${data.value()}"
            log += "$line\n"
            Log.i(tag, line)
        }

        line = "[request body] ${request.requestBody()}"
        log += "$line\n"
        Log.i(tag, line)

        return log
    }

    private fun log(response: Connection.Response): String {
        var line = ""
        var log = "\n== RESPONSE ==\n"

        Log.i(tag, "== RESPONSE ==")
        log += logBase(response)

        line = "[code] ${response.statusCode()}"
        log += "$line\n"
        Log.i(tag, line)

        line = "[status msg] ${response.statusMessage()}"
        log += "$line\n"
        Log.i(tag, line)

        line = "[body] ${response.body()}"
        log += "$line\n"
        Log.i(tag, line)

        Log.i(tag, "========================================")

        return log
    }

    private fun logBase(base: Connection.Base<*>): String {
        var line = ""
        var log = ""
        for (header in base.headers()) {
            line = "[header] ${header.key}=${header.value}"
            log += "$line\n"
            Log.i(tag, line)
        }
        for (cookie in base.cookies()) {
            line = "[cookie] ${cookie.key}: ${cookie.value}"
            log += "$line\n"
            Log.i(tag, line)
        }
        return log
    }

    override fun execute(): Connection.Response {
        var logs = log(request())
        val response = delegate.execute()
        logs += log(response)
        if (saveFile)
            logs.saveToFile("request_log") //do something to save your log in a file if its necesary
        return response
    }

    override fun ignoreContentType(ignoreContentType: Boolean): Connection {
        delegate.ignoreContentType(ignoreContentType)
        return this
    }

    override fun postDataCharset(charset: String?): Connection {
        delegate.postDataCharset(charset)
        return this
    }

    override fun get(): Document {
        return delegate.get()
    }

    override fun post(): Document {
        return delegate.post()
    }

    /** Continue implementing necessary methods for Connection */

}
```

Now just declare your request using `LoggerHttpConnection` instead `Jsoup` and everything will work

```
Connection.Response res = LoggerHttpConnection.connect("LOGIN_URL_HERE")
        .data("user", "USER", "pass", "PASS")
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .execute();
```