# API returning 200 for browser and 500 for Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

When I call an API from the browser it returns a status code of 200 and a JSON object. However if I call the API from Java / JSoup, it returns a status code of 500 and "HTTP error fetching URL, Status=500"

```
String json = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .ignoreContentType(true)
    .timeout(5000)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2")
    .ignoreContentType(true)
    .execute()
    .body();
System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: I would use web developer tools to see exactly what is being sent by the browser and JSoup and see what the differences are.  Probably some header is affecting the response.

Answer (score 1):

In your browser, use the developer mode to view details of the HTTP request.

When running your Java program, get a debug log of the HTTP request (see: [Jsoup http logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349875/jsoup-http-logging) )

Compare every detail of the request -- make sure all the headers are the same, or that you're certain they are not relevant.

If you have access to the server, look for messages in the server log giving details of the cause of the `500`.