# IHS (Apache) 400 Error when adding UUID header to HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, apache, http-headers, httpurlconnection

I need to add a header ("correlationIdHeader") to a *GET* Request using Java's **HttpUrlConnection**. However the server (IBM Http Server - built on Apache) answers with a 400 Error and the following info:

```
Request header field is missing ':' separator
```

My code:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("correlationIdHeader", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
conn.setRequestMethod(HttpMethod.GET.name());
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", contentType);

int responseCode= conn.getResponseCode();
```

Any idea what could be happening here?

**EDIT**: it has to do with UUID.randomUUID().toString(). I don't know why but it doesn't like UUID's format. Why?

Comment: I would try putting the setRequestMethod before setting the first property but I don't really know if that is the problem.

Comment: What does the UUID looks like? Does it have a space in it or some other special character?

Comment: Tried moving requestMethod but didn't work. UUID is something like this: 00000000-0000-0000-C000-000000000046. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: You could try and see that is actually being sent with wireshark or by writing a simple server yourself.

Comment: This can help seeing what is sent on the wire:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445919/how-to-enable-wire-logging-for-a-java-httpurlconnection-traffic