# Cloudant - Connection Pooling

Tags: scala, database-connection, ibm-cloud, connection-pooling, cloudant

I am trying connection pooling with cloudant database. From what I understand, the cloudant database inherently does connection pooling with the default parameter of max_connections = 6. [max_connections code](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/blob/515cf156751cd67d714a206d1bc39a5489f8c156/cloudant-client/src/main/java/com/cloudant/client/api/ClientBuilder.java). The code snippet required is at line 130.

I have a working application written in scala using akka-http with the following initialisation :

```
val client: CloudantClient = ClientBuilder.account(<accountdetails>)
.username(<my user name>)
.password(<my password>).maxConnections(20)
.build()
println("creating database")
val db: Database = client.database("exampledb", false)
println("created");
```

My question is how do I confirm if the connection pooling works as intended for a basic get function from lets say an example student Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think akka-http will have an impact here unless it replaces the `java.netHttpURLConnection`. The `CloudantClient` uses the `java.net.HttpURLConnection` class to communicate with the Cloudant database. The implementation of `HttpURLConnection` is provided by the JVM by default or by OkHttp if you added that dependency. As per the [documentation for connection pooling](http://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.7.0/overview-summary.html#Connection%20pooling) the behaviour changes if you are using the optional OkHttp client or not.  The [`maxConnections` method](http://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.7.0/com/cloudant/client/api/ClientBuilder.html#maxConnections-int-) only changes the connection pool size if you are using the OkHttp dependency. For the default `HttpURLConnection` the pool size is configured by JVM properties.

As per [this documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.7.0/overview-summary.html#Logging) it is possible to enable logging for the java-cloudant client. As the pool use is transparent to the client code if you want to validate whether a connection is created or leased from the pool you will need logging for the underlying `HttpURLConnection`. For more information about the log string for the default `HttpURLConnection` see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12339718).

If you are concerned whether pooling is working or not, you may also find the discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/issues/247) relevant. The default JVM implementation purges connections from the pool after a very short idle time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Am sorry, but did not fully understand you. So, if I don't include the Okhttp dependency, will the connection pooling not work?
Also, I went through this link : https://gitlab.com/Guy1394/java-cloudant/tree/117-url-encode-session#connectoptions and from what I understand in the section about "Resource Sharing", I think connection pooling should work. Isn't?
Thanks for your time

Comment: Connection pooling still works if you don't include OkHttp, but whether it is enabled and how big the pool is are controlled by the JVM properties `http.maxConnections` and `http.keepAlive` (see this [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html)) not the `ClientBuilder.maxConnections` method.

Comment: Also the gitlab link you provided is a fork of an old version. The official java-cloudant repo is [here](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant) and includes links to the javadoc.