# Error 415 for WSDL SOAP Webservice Java client

Tags: java, wsdl, content-type, soap-client, http-status-code-415

this time i will be needing some help with an error that i can't find where is the problem.

I developed a very simple java code to consume a web service but when I run it i'm getting this nasty error: "Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL: [http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso/NumberToWords"](http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso/NumberToWords%22)

Investigating about this error it said that this has something to do with the Content-Type not been supported, so downloaded SoapUI 5.6.0 to see what the WS was waiting for and it seems correct to me.

Here is my code:

```
package principal;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class PruebaWS {
    public void getNumber(int number){
        String wsURL = "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso/NumberToWords";
        URL url = null;
        URLConnection connection = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
        String responseString = null;
        String outputString = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        
        String xmlInput = 
                "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:web=\"http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/\">" +
                "   <soapenv:Header/>" +
                "   <soapenv:Body>" +
                "      <web:NumberToWords>" +
                "         <web:ubiNum>" + number +"</web:ubiNum>" +
                "      </web:NumberToWords>" +
                "   </soapenv:Body>" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>";
        
        try {
            url = new URL(wsURL);
            connection = url.openConnection();
            httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            
            byte[] buffer = new byte[xmlInput.length()];
            buffer = xmlInput.getBytes();
            
            String SOAPAction = "";
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", SOAPAction);
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(buffer.length));
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
            httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/xml");
            httpConn.setDoInput(true);
            httpConn.setDoOutput(true);
            httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
            
            out = httpConn.getOutputStream();
            out.write(buffer);
            out.close();
            
            // Lee la respuesta y escribe a un output estándard
            isr = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream());
            in = new BufferedReader(isr);
            
            while ((responseString = in.readLine()) != null)
                outputString = outputString + responseString;
            
            System.out.println(outputString);
            System.out.println("");
            
            // Obtiene la respuesta desde la llamada al webService
            Document document = parseXmlFile(outputString);
            
            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("m:NumberToWordsResponse");
            String webServiceResponse = nodeList.item(0).getTextContent();
            System.out.println("La respuesta del web service es: " + webServiceResponse);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    
    private Document parseXmlFile(String in){
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(in));
            return db.parse(is);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error during Runtime:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL:
> http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso/NumberToWords
> at principal.PruebaWS.getNumber(PruebaWS.java:83)   at
> principal.Main.main(Main.java:6) Caused by: java.io.IOException:
> Server returned HTTP response code: 415 for URL:
> http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso/NumberToWords
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1919)
> at
> java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
> at principal.PruebaWS.getNumber(PruebaWS.java:67)   ... 1 more
> C:\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The
> following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java
> returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Any help will be valuable.

Comment: have you tried to remove the charset part on the content type just in case... Also you can try with "application/xml" as the Content-Type header. If still the issue I recommend enabling logging to check the actual request that is being sent ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445919/how-to-enable-wire-logging-for-a-java-httpurlconnection-traffic

Comment: No luck at all, just the same error over and over... i can't do anything about the WS it self since it does not belongs to me, so not a single chance to enabling logging.

Comment: you can always enable logging on the client side to check what you are sending

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue using Postman and was able to resolve. Change the Content-Type header from application/xml to text/xml

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after investigating for quite some time I discovered that this error had something to do with the webservice it self, i swapped it with another and it worked with no issue. Lesson learned: NOT all webservices out there work as they should.