# How to format the property "sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = ALL" to log4j.xml?

Tags: java, log4j

I need to add to my logging.properties the line:

```
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level = ALL
```

But this file is generated using log4j.xml, which is in xml format. And I'm not finding how to correctly format this property to xml to generate this line.

using log4j-1.2.8, JRE and JDK 1.8_181, Wildfly 10.1.0.Final

Comment: Well ... I guess, the [official documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML) tells you how ...

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose sorry I really know nothing about log4j configurations. I'm trying to find a patter here to set a new one, but looks like each one have a specific tag, and there's no tag for "HttpURLConnection", also there's no "HttpURLConnection" on the official documentation. I'll read to try to find where it would fit.

Comment: What does this have to do with WildFly?

Comment: Not every class support log4j , if the class does not use log4j to logging something, even you add `xxx.level=ALL`, it will output nothing. HttpURLConnection.java (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java)

Comment: google `github log4j.xml` have a lots of example code. example (https://gist.github.com/mwicat/1460284), you can find `<logger name="org.jivesoftware.openfire.fastpath">`

Comment: @Student: what version of Log4j are you using (by the name `log4j.xml` of the config file it appears it is the EOLed Log4j 1.2)? What version of the JRE? JRE components log in different ways (but never use an external library) and Log4j 1.2 has a different configuration than Log4j 2.x.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz log4j-1.2.8, jre 1.8_181

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, you will not be able to configure the logging level for `sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection` using Log4j, no matter if you use `properties` or `xml` configuration files.

As you can see in the [source code of the `HttpURLConnection` class](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java), its logging is based in [`PlatformLogger`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/util/logging/PlatformLogger.java), which in turn uses `java.util.logging`.

The `PlatformLogger` javadoc describes how it should be configured:

> Platform logger provides an API for the JRE components to log
> messages.  This enables the runtime components to eliminate the
> static dependency of the logging facility and also defers the
> java.util.logging initialization until it is enabled.
> In addition, the PlatformLogger API can be used if the logging
> module does not exist.
>
> If the logging facility is not enabled, the platform loggers
> will output log messages per the default logging configuration
> (see below). In this implementation, it does not log the
> the stack frame information issuing the log message.
>
> When the logging facility is enabled (at startup or runtime),
> the java.util.logging.Logger will be created for each platform
> logger and all log messages will be forwarded to the Logger
> to handle.
>
> Logging facility is "enabled" when one of the following
> conditions is met:
>
> 1. a system property "java.util.logging.config.class" or
>    "java.util.logging.config.file" is set
> 2. java.util.logging.LogManager or java.util.logging.Logger
>    is referenced that will trigger the logging initialization.
>
> Default logging configuration:
> global logging level = INFO
> handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
> java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
> java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter =  java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

Basically, you need to configure the system property `java.util.logging.config.file` pointing to an appropriate `properties` file with the required properties:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level=ALL
```

Please, consider review this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445919/how-to-enable-wire-logging-for-a-java-httpurlconnection-traffic), it provides different examples and further information about how to do it.

As suggested in that question, you can use the system property `javax.net.debug` as well:

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

If you want to integrate Log4j and `java.util.logging`, you can try using libraries like [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/) and the corresponding [bridges](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html). [This related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869945/how-to-send-java-util-logging-to-log4j) provides more information.

Answer (score 1):

**Remark**: Since Log4j 1.2.8 is [almost 20 years old](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/changes-report.html), declared end-of-life 8 years ago and with [several outstanding vulnerabilities](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html), I don't believe you want to use it.

As you can see in [jccampanero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75177502/11748454), the `HttpURLConnection` class uses `PlatformLogger` for logging, which in Java 7 or 8 delegates all logging to `java.util.logging.LogManager`.

Several alternative implementations of `java.util.logging.LogManager` exist, but WildFly uses its own implementation called [JBoss LogManager](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_build_of_quarkus/1.11/html/configuring_logging_with_quarkus/con-jboss-logmanager-and-supported-logging-frameworks_quarkus-configuring-logging), which is the easiest to use. To modify your logging configuration, you just need to edit your server's configuration and add:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
    ...
    <logger category="sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
</subsystem>
```

(cf. [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging%20Configuration.html)).